# getBoundingClientRect error on Android WebView

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, android-webview

I'm writing a wrapper app for a website which uses Google Maps and Geolocation. The problem I ran into is that in the normal browser the page functions normally, but in WebView the two-finger zoom doesn't work and it literally **floods** the log with this error:

`05-24 08:14:28.504: E/Web Console(21166): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of null at http://<mydomain>/index.php:28`

The trouble is, the function is only used in Google's JS code, not in our codes, so I don't have so much power over it. How should I begin to resolve this?

Here's some (possibly) relevant source for you, with minimal censorship.

```
myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
        mk.setTitle(getString(R.string.loading));
        mk.setProgress(progress * 100);
        if(progress == 100) {
            mk.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        }
    }

    public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
        callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
    }
});
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setUserAgentString(getString(R.string.useragent));
webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
webSettings.setGeolocationDatabasePath("/data/data/com.mypackage.myapp");
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JSInterface(this), "androidapp");
myWebView.loadUrl(HOMEURL);
```

Answer (score 2):

Whatever object is used to call `getBoundingClientRect` is `null` -- so there's the start of your problem. Can you look at the original JS code (on the web site, that calls Google's API)?

Comment: The site doesn't use that function call, it's only found inside Google's API, in a script called with the URL `http://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/7/17/%7Bcommon,map,util,geometry,directions%7D.js`, so it's pretty tough to edit...

Comment: That still points to where the problem is: a `<div>` or other DOM element used by GMaps, and the script wants to know its mensurations. Sounds to me like the script was passed the name of a `<div>` (the one where the map will be displayed) that doesn't exist.

Comment: Okay, so how can this be debugged? Since the error only shows up in WebView and not in any browser, I can't use the usual debug tools.

Comment: Look at the code that calls the GMaps script. There's some JS code on your side too right? You are loading `HOMEURL`. I'm assuming that's still on your side right? So look at the HTML and JS there. I'd start with the name of the DIV that will receive the Google map.

Comment: That can't be the case, since the error is triggered even with a basic page like this test page: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/afQAAG4w)

Comment: Looking at the source code of the GMaps script, the object that's passed around, `a`, is most probably the div. And if the script says that it's null, it means that there is a snafu when you load the page in a webview. Or more accurately, when you do the two-finger zoom. That's the code that probably has a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when setting a custom user agent for the webview. After I changed it back to default user agent, problem is solved.